# Query regarding the upload of multiple files in different browsers in Angular (inconsistent behaviors)

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, browser, mozilla

In my Angular project, I have a simple multiple file upload:

```
<input
  type="file"
  class="display-none"
  #file
  (change)="onFilesSelectedForUpload()"
  onclick="value = null"
  multiple
/>
```

Based on some investigations, most browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) have a limit of 6 connections per hostname [reference](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/cloud/latest/manual/html/designguide/solution/support/connection_limitations.html) and I was expecting the same behaviour from them, but it did not happen.

- **Chrome**

When there are 6 files being uploaded (each with a size of 100 MB), and I try to access the list of groups, the last request is not processed and it stays in pending status. The screenshot shows what the Network tab looks like -> [Check Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37haJ.png)

But when a file is successfully uploaded, and the number of files in progress goes to 5, then the request is processed and the list of groups is displayed.

- **Edge**

I repeated the same scenario using Microsoft Edge and I encountered the same behavior.

- **Mozilla Firefox**

Using Mozilla, I observed an unstable behavior. When I upload the same 6 files, the next request (to display the list of groups) is not processed. In the first test, groups are displayed when there were *5 files* in progress, in the second test only when there was only *1 file* in progress, and in the *third* test when there were 4 files in progress.

I would highly appreciate your help with any information on why this is happening and what could be the possible cause.

Thank you.